# Is iteration via Collections.synchronizedSet(...).forEach() guaranteed to be thread safe?

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety, java-8

As we know, iterating over a concurrent collection is not thread safe by default, so one cannot use:

```
Set<E> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
//fill with data
for (E e : set) {
    process(e);
}
```

This happens as data may be added during iteration, because there is no exclusive lock on `set`.

This is describe in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-) of `Collections.synchronizedSet`:

> public static  Set synchronizedSet(Set s)
>
> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) set backed by the specified set. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing set is accomplished through the returned set.
>
> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned set when iterating over it:
>
> Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
>         ...
>      `synchronized (s) {
>         Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
>         while (i.hasNext())
>             foo(i.next());
>   }`
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

**However**, this does not apply to `Set.forEach`, which inherits the default method `forEach` from [Iterable.forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

Now I looked into the source code, and here we can see that we have the following structure:

1. We ask for a `Collections.synchronizedSet()`.
2. We get one:

   ```
   public static <T> Set<T> synchronizedSet(Set<T> s) {
       return new SynchronizedSet<>(s);
   }

   ...

   static class SynchronizedSet<E>
         extends SynchronizedCollection<E>
         implements Set<E> {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 487447009682186044L;

       SynchronizedSet(Set<E> s) {
           super(s);
       }
       SynchronizedSet(Set<E> s, Object mutex) {
           super(s, mutex);
       }

       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (this == o)
               return true;
           synchronized (mutex) {return c.equals(o);}
       }
       public int hashCode() {
           synchronized (mutex) {return c.hashCode();}
       }
   }
   ```
3. It extends `SynchronizedCollection`, which has the following *interesting* methods next to the obvious ones:

   ```
   // Override default methods in Collection
   @Override
   public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> consumer) {
       synchronized (mutex) {c.forEach(consumer);}
   }
   @Override
   public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
       synchronized (mutex) {return c.removeIf(filter);}
   }
   @Override
   public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
       return c.spliterator(); // Must be manually synched by user!
   }
   @Override
   public Stream<E> stream() {
       return c.stream(); // Must be manually synched by user!
   }
   @Override
   public Stream<E> parallelStream() {
       return c.parallelStream(); // Must be manually synched by user!
   }
   ```

The `mutex` used here is the same object as to which *all* operations of `Collections.synchronizedSet` lock to.

Now we can, judging by the *implementation* say that it is thread safe to use `Collections.synchronizedSet(...).forEach(...)`, but is it also thread safe *by specification*?

(Confusingly enough, `Collections.synchronizedSet(...).stream().forEach(...)` is *not* thread safe by implementation, and the verdict of the specification seems to be unknown aswell.)

Comment: Good find! It doesn't appear to be thread-safe by the spec, but it sounds like the spec (specifically, for that method) should be updated.

Answer (score 11):

As you wrote, judging by implementation, `forEach()` is thread-safe **for the collections  provided with JDK** (see disclaimer below) as it requires monitor of mutex to be acquired to proceed.

> Is it also thread safe by specification?

My opinion - no, and here is an explanation. `Collections.synchronizedXXX()` javadoc, rewritten in short words, says - "all methods are thread-safe except for those used for iterating over it".

My other, although very subjective argument is what *yshavit* wrote - unless told/read that, consider API/class/whatever not thread-safe.

Now, let's take a closer look at the javadocs. I guess I may state that method `forEach()` is used to iterate over it, so, following the advice from javadoc, we should consider it not thread-safe, although it is opposite to reality (implementation).

Anyway, I agree with *yshavit*'s statement that the documentation should be updated as this is most likely a documentation, not implementation flaw. But, no one can say for sure except for JDK developers, see concerns below.

The last point I'd like to mention within this discussion - we can assume that custom collection can be wrapped with `Collections.synchronizedXXX()`, and the implementation of `forEach()` of this collection can be... can be anything. The collection might perform asynchronous processing of elements within the `forEach()` method, spawn a thread for each element... it is bounded only by author's imagination, and **synchronized(mutex) wrap cannot guarantee thread-safety for such cases**. That particular issue might be the reason not to declare `forEach()` method as thread-safe..

Comment: This goes against the standard advice for thread-safety, which is that if something isn't explicitly stated to be thread-safe, you should assume it's not thread-safe. By your reasoning, `synchronizedSet.stream().forEach(...)` should also be thread-safe, but it isn't (as the OP points out).

Comment: @yshavit Your argument is really good, it made me change my opinion :)

Comment: Glad to help, and +1 now. :) I'm going to keep my comment up, if that's okay, in case a future googler comes across this and would be helped by the additional comment (and general advice).

Comment: Now the implementation makes no sense though as then the documentation already implies locking, so there would be absolutely no use in locking it in the implementation.

Comment: @skiwi I'd agree that implementation contradicts documentation, but IMO this is a documentation bug. They should've added the statement that there is no need to synchronize above `forEach` calls..

Comment: My colleague pointed at custom collections custom `forEach()`, so I added a disclaimer.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev I still need to take a closer look at it, sorry for the delay, but an accept will follow.

Comment: @skiwi Actually I'd be honored to continue that discussion, if neccesary. Just FYI.

Answer (score 6):

It’s worth to have a look at the [documentation of `Collections.synchronizedCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection-java.util.Collection-) rather than `Collections.synchronizedSet()` as *that* documentation has been cleaned up already:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when traversing it
>   via `Iterator`, `Spliterator` or `Stream`: …

I think, this makes it pretty clear that there is a distinction between the iteration via an object other than the synchronized `Collection` itself and using its `forEach` method. But even with the old wording you can draw the conclusion that there is such a distinction:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned set *when iterating over it*:…

<sup>(emphasis by me)</sup>

Compare to the [documentation for `Iterable.forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Performs the given action for each element of the `Iterable` until all elements have been processed or the action throws an exception.

While it is clear to the developer that there must be an (internal) iteration happening to achieve this, this iteration is an implementation detail. From the given specification’s wording it’s just a (meta-)action for performing an action to each element.

When using that method, the *user* is *not* iterating over the elements and hence not responsible for the synchronization mentioned in the `Collections.synchronized…` documentation.

However, that’s a bit subtle and it’s good that the [documentation of `synchronizedCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection-java.util.Collection-) lists the cases for manual synchronization explicitly and I think the documentation of the other methods should be adapted as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @Holger said, the [doc clearly says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection-java.util.Collection-) user must manually synchronize collections returned by `Collections.synchronizedXyz()` when tranversing it via `Iterator`:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when traversing it via Iterator, Spliterator or Stream:
>
> ```
> Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
>  ...
> synchronized (c) {
>     Iterator i = c.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>        foo(i.next());
> }
> ```

I want to explain a bit more about code.

Consider [`Collections.synchronizedList()` method](https://github.com/jdk-mirror/openjdk8/blob/d15d915ceb0f6a5bfab067a23a9e4a674dac3da8/java/util/Collections.java#L2376). It returns [Collections.SynchronizedList](https://github.com/jdk-mirror/openjdk8/blob/d15d915ceb0f6a5bfab067a23a9e4a674dac3da8/java/util/Collections.java#L2391) class instance, which extends [`SynchronizedCollection`](https://github.com/jdk-mirror/openjdk8/blob/d15d915ceb0f6a5bfab067a23a9e4a674dac3da8/java/util/Collections.java#L1998) which defines [`iterator()`](https://github.com/jdk-mirror/openjdk8/blob/d15d915ceb0f6a5bfab067a23a9e4a674dac3da8/java/util/Collections.java#L2030) as follows:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return c.iterator(); // Must be manually synched by user!
}
```

Compare this with other methods of `SynchronizedCollections`, for example:

```
public String toString() {
    synchronized (mutex) {return c.toString();}
}
```

Thus `SynchronizedList` inherits `iterator()` from `SynchronizedCollection`, which needs to be synched manually by user.